# AWS Elasticsearch cluster method to update `http.max_content_length`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an AWS managed Elasticsearch cluster that needs http.max_content_length to be updated.

API here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2

The only way I've seen to do this is to SSH into an instance, add `http.max_content_length="1000mb"` to the `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` config and restart the Elasticsearch server.

However, I'm not sure how that works for AWS managed Elasticsearch instances?

It looks like AWS might have hard limits(?):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html#network-limits

Any help (via Terraform, kibana, curl... ) would be much appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK it's not configurable in AWS' managed ES.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks for the reply!  I think you're right too, but wanted to check in case there was a hack or something someone had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS ES has a max HTTP payload limit which depends on the instance type used (10MB or 100MB). This cannot be changed on ES level as its a managed service and AWS does not provide access to ES .yml config.

Comment: Thanks for the additional verification!